# Express router for accepting a URL as route parameter

Tags: node.js, express

Imagine you want to build a webpage health checker. I want users to send GET requests to `https://localhost/check/{valid_url_here}` and I send a request to that URL. I couldn't find proper way of writing the correct router for this in Express.

This is the closest answer but it trims the url after `?` adding it to `req.query`

```
router.get('/check/:url*', (req, res) => {})
```

so when URL is `https://example.com/?print=1` the variable `req.params.url` misses the `?print` part... I want to capture **anything** that comes after `/check/`

Comment: If you want that to be counted as the path parameter not the query it needs to be _encoded_.

Comment: FYI, `https://localhost/check/https://example.com/?print=1` is NOT a valid URL.  You need to encode the second URL with [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) so it doesn't contain illegal characters that are not allowed in the path of a URL.  And, then you should probably use a query parameter as in `https://localhost/check?url=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F%3Fprint%3D1`.  Then, you can just do `console.log(req.query.url)` in Express.

Comment: `encodeURI("https://localhost/check/https://example.com/?print=1")` returns the URL without any additional encoding. Isn't it valid then?

Comment: @jfriend00 IDK about validity according to standards, but this convention is pretty common in systems doing some job on a URL checkout some image proxy servers e.g. https://github.com/willnorris/imageproxy that are using this type of URL which I find pretty handy, prefix your URL with some string and that's it.

Comment: Yes, you can do it that way using `encodeURI()` too as that will make a legal URL out of the path.  It's a bit easier to set up the route and do things in Express with `?url=xxx` and `req.query.url`.  Your choice.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen it does, because you're encoding it _as the whole URL_. `print=1` is then part of the query not part of the path, which is exactly what the OP's problem is to start with. `encodeURIComponent("https://example.com/?print=1")` certainly doesn't return it unencoded...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
router.use("/check", function(req, res) {
  var url = req.url.substring(1);
});
```

Then https://localhost/check/https://example.com/?print=1 leads to `url = "https://example.com/?print=1"`.